# Use "beforeShowDay" with Bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, typo3

I use Bootstrap 3.

Into a Bootstrap-datepicker, I have to enable dates only when there is some news get from my CMS TYPO3 v7 for this dates.

I success to get the dates into a data attribute from a TYPO3 viewhelper :

```
<input id="agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer" class="agenda-date-selector-datepicker" value="{f:format.date(date:\'{weekDate}\',format:\'d-m-Y\')}" data-dates='{enableDates -> ul:Datepicker()}'>
```

> (Don't take care of "values" it's not important here).

Into my JS I enter into my "true" return.
`(alert("true");` is display 10 time but I have 13 dates... strange...
And no dates are disabled into datepicker.

I adapt this working model to make the code http://jsfiddle.net/vCJ2u/198/ but this model use jQuery UI.

**Here my code :**

```js
$(function(){
 
 if($('.section-agenda-date-selector').length){
  availableDates = $('#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer').data('dates');
  alert(availableDates);
  $("#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer").datepicker({
   maxViewMode: 2,
   language: "fr",
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   //startDate: '+1d',
   //weekStart: 1,
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   beforeShowDay: function(dt){
    console.log([available(dt), "" ]);
    return [available(dt), "" ];
   }
  });
 
  initAgendaListe();
 }

 
});

function available(date) {
 dmy = ( '0' + date.getDate() ).slice( -2 ) + "-" + ( '0' + (date.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 ) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
 
 if ($.inArray(dmy.toString(), availableDates) != -1){
//   alert("true");
  return {
   enabled : true
  };
 } else {
  return {
   enabled : false
  };
 }

}

function initAgendaListe(){   
 // au click sur un élément du datepicker
 $('.agenda-date-selector-datepicker').on('change', function(){
  window.location.href = '/index.php?id=19&eventsbyweek='+$(this).val();
 });
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="section section-grey section-agenda-date-selector">
...
</div>

<div class="agenda-datepicker datepicker-wrapper">
  <div class="input-datepicker-hidden">
   <input id="agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer" class="agenda-date-selector-datepicker" value="" data-dates='["15-06-2017","20-06-2017","29-06-2017","29-08-2017","11-09-2017","15-09-2017","17-09-2017","18-09-2017","27-09-2017","28-09-2017","29-09-2017","30-09-2017","31-10-2017"]'>
  </div>
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer">
  <i class="icon icon-left icon-agenda"></i>
  Choisir une date
  </label>
  
</div>
```

An idea please ? Any help is welcome ! :)
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps!

use bootstrap [beforeShowDay](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday) option to enable dates.

```js
$(function() {
var datesEnabled = ['2017-9-10', '2017-9-15', '2017-9-25'];
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
  var allDates = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  if(datesEnabled.indexOf(allDates) != -1)
  return true;
  else
  return false;
   }
});
});
```

```css
td.day.disabled {
opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to disabled but enabled some dates... So disabled all dates per default and enabled only the dates into my array.
So the http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday method seem to exist for that... ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Amal :)
It's working with your updated exemple !

BUT : If I replace your array by my array returned by the data-attribute :
`var datesEnabled = $('#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer').data('dates');` it's not working :( Every dates are disabled...

but `alert(datesEnabled);` display same output than your hard coding array...

This can be a format problem ?!

Comment: Thanks a lot Amal :)
It's working with your updated exemple !

BUT : If I replace your array by my array returned by the data-attribute :
`var datesEnabled = $('#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer').data('dates');` it's not working :( Every dates are disabled...

but `alert(datesEnabled);` display same output than your hard coding array...

Maybe the problem is because of data attribute... my array is not an array but a string comma separated...
`alert(datesEnabled);` display `2017-09-15,2017-09-17,2017-09-18`not `['2017-09-15','2017-09-17','2017-09-18']`
... ?

Comment: With Firebug, the value of the date attribute is strange :

`data-dates="[" 2017-06-15","2017-06-20","2017-06-29","2017-08-29","2017-09-11","2017-09-15","2017-09-17","2017-09-18","2017-09-27","2017-09-28","2017-09-29","2017-09-30","2017-10-31"]"=""`

I try to modify my php return with the "JSON_HEX_QUOT" constant but without any success... `return json_encode($enableDates, JSON_HEX_QUOT);`

Any idea ?

Comment: Now I use str_replace into my php to return the good value into the data-attribute :
`$enableDates = json_encode($enableDates);
return str_replace("\"", "'", $enableDates);`

Now the value of "data-dates" into Firebug is good :
`<input data-dates="['2017-06-15','2017-06-20','2017-06-29','2017-08-29','2017-09-11','2017-09-15','2017-09-17','2017-09-18','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29','2017-09-30','2017-10-31']">` The alert output is identical, with "[]" ... but still not working...
I think the format return by my php is not good because the "alert()" don't have to display the [ ]...

Comment: Now I try into php to return a string :
`$enableDates = implode("','", $enableDates);
return "[".$enableDates."]";`
but same result than above...

Comment: O... I think the problem come from that into your example array month are with one number : "15/9/2017" but my returned dates are make with 2 numbers for month : "15/09/2017".
So I never enter the "true"...

Comment: So I try like this : 
`beforeShowDay: function (date) {
 var allDates = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (0+(date.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + date.getDate();
...`
Without any success...

Comment: Thank you so much bro. you saved me, realy great solution.

Answer (score 3):

ok ! Now it's working !
Here my code : https://jsfiddle.net/scanx/per1syfr/2/

```js
$(function(){
    
    if($('.section-agenda-date-selector').length){
//         var datesEnabled = $('#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer').data('dates');
        var datesEnabled = ['2017-09-21','2017-09-15','2017-09-25'];
        alert(datesEnabled);

        $("#agenda-date-selector-datepicker-footer").datepicker({
            maxViewMode: 2,
            language: "fr",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            weekStart: 1,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var allDates = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ( '0' + (date.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 ) + "-" + ( '0' + date.getDate() ).slice( -2 );
                if(datesEnabled.indexOf(allDates) != -1)
        {
            alert(allDates + " : dispo");
                    return true;
                }
        else
        {
            alert(allDates + " : pas dispo")
                    return false;
        }
            }

        });
    
        initAgendaListe();
    }    
});
```

Thanks to [Amal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7677884/amal) who help me so much ! :)